# Tackling Disconnection Problem in Gatan Digital Micrograph - Any Suggestions and Solutions?

Tags: dm-script

My apologies that my post is to seek for suggestions/solutions but not particularly on the scripts problem itself. Unfortunately i am not sure where else i can ask this question.

Here it goes for the problem.. for all of you who have been using DM for collecting images, you might encounter occassional disconnection from the TEM. As a result, you might unknowingly save images with the wrong scalebar. I would like to tackle this problem but i didn't have a good solution to it. My TEM is from JEOL so i am using either the TEMCON or TEMCENTER depending on the TEM model. What i intially thought to tackle this problem is to use AutoLT to extract the magnification data periodically and save it in a txt file in the share folder created in the Gatan computer. Then from DM, i will write a script that can periodically use the magnification status in dm and crosscheck with the magnification value in the txt file. When discrepancy occurs, the script will prompt this disconnection error to user so that he can restart the connection.

What i would like to ask if anyone has a better and elegant solution to my problem? All suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please note that this is exclusively about coding in DigitalMicrograph using its internal scripting language and/or Python. Your problem sounds like something you might want to report to your Gatan service provider and/or the Gatan webpage (www.gatan.com).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question does not related to coding and is a general service request.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advices! In that case i better contact Gatan for more advices on this!